# How can I create instances of external dependencies in a function in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs

I was implementing queues using NestJs and wanted to use a separate process functionality. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues#separate-processes

So in this case, I wanted to call a function which is being used in one of my services.But I am not sure how I can do this since as per the documentation:

> Please note that because your function is being executed in a forked
> process, Dependency Injection (and IoC container) won't be available.
> That means that your processor function will need to contain (or
> create) all instances of external dependencies it needs.

How do I access my service function by accessing the external dependancy?

Answer (score 0):

The way to get various dependencies is to create the instance of the app module again and use it to get the instance

Assuming the app.module.ts is your main entry module

```js
function async yourJobHandler(job: Job) {
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

 const exampleService = app.get<ExampleService)(ExampleService);

 // rest of your job code
}
```